# Sticky footer in master page

Tags: asp.net, css, master-pages, sticky-footer

After days of searching for some code that makes the footer stick to the end of the page, I finally found something that works.

But now I realized, It only sticks to the end of the page if you have that specific resolution.
What if someone has a bigger screen or is looking at the page in full view, then it doesn’t work anymore.

Please some help?

And also, I know about the oh-so-famous sticky-footer sites. Can't seem to find an answer here
I need specific help with my code.

Thanks!

MASTERPAGE:

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div class="page">
        <div class="header">
        </div>

        <div class="main">
            <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
                <div class="wrapper" />
            </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
        </div>

        <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="FooterPlaceHolder" runat="server">
        </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
    </div>
</form>
```

CONTENTPAGE aspx

```
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" Runat="Server">
    <h2>Knowledge Base</h2>

    <div class="push"></div>
</asp:Content>

<asp:Content ID="Content3" ContentPlaceHolderID="FooterPlaceHolder" Runat="Server">
    <div class="footer">
        &copy; "companyName"
    </div>
</asp:Content>
```

CSS:

```
html {
    height: 100%;*/
}
body
{
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0px;
}
.page
{
    width: 1200px;
    margin: auto;
    height: 100%;
}
.main
{
    text-align: left;
    padding: 5px 15px;
    margin-top: 10px;
}
.footer
{
    text-align: center;
}
.wrapper
{
    min-height: 100%;
    height: auto !important; 
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0px auto -449px; 
}
.push 
{
    clear: both;
    height: 449px;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Why not take the standard approach:

```
<footer>
      <p>&copy; <%: DateTime.Now.Year %> - Sometext</p>
</footer>
```

Css:

```
footer {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 10px;
}
```

Edit: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LZAMd/). Excactly the same code. The footer is always at the bottom, no matter which way you resize the browser window.

Comment: This seems like the most logical solution. But it doesn't work.

Comment: I have tested it in WebForms application. Did def. work. See JSFiddle for details

Comment: Does it also work with a masterpage? Because that seems to cause some problems. Can you post the JSFiddle please?

Comment: What I've posted was tested with a master page in Asp.net WebForms.

Comment: I have noticed that the problem is the tag <form>... but i have not yet found the solution

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I solved this issue using the following piece of code. Place it inside the head elements of the master page:

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.js"></script>  
<script type="text/javascript">  
   $(window).bind("load", function () {  
       var footer = $("#footer");  
       var pos = footer.position();  
       var height = $(window).height();  
       height = height - pos.top;  
       height = height - footer.height();
       if (height > 0) {  
           footer.css({  
               'margin-top': height + 'px'  
           });  
       }  
   });  
</script>
</head>
```

After that insert any custom footer inside the following div which does the trick.

```
<div id="footer"></div>
```

It also adjusts the footer very well to pages with much content. I found this solution  [here](https://www.codeproject.com/questions/614579/how-to-set-footer-at-bottom-only-using-master-page).

Comment: Thanks. I had to make some tweaks to it, and here's a working link:
https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/7dc621/sticky-footer-in-master-page-using-Asp-Net/